# ISO diff -b that ignores only whitespaces that do not affect indentation (...in mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, diff, indentation

Working with a friend, the usual whitespace wars. Possibly a new take, leading to my search for a variant of diff -b.

E.g. we both prefer not to have trailing whitespace on a line, but some crept into his code.  I usually have emacs configured to delete trailing whitespace
    (add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
so none creeps into my code, but it also deletes the trailing whitespace in his code.

Which trailing whitespace (1) he wishes had not been placed in the file, but (2) he wants to preserve, to minimize diffs.

He doesn't want to use "diff -b" because that ignores meaningful changes in indentation, like changes in indentation level. (Or at least that's why I dislike diff -b, although diff -b is my usual.)

So, my question: is there any diff out there that has a variant of diff -b that can ignore changes in whitespace that do not affect indentation,

- such as trailing whitespace,
- and (lower priority) possibly also changes such as tab related - e.g. at beginning of line  --> , i.e. the elision of  spaces that do not affect indentation because of subsequent tabs (for some tab width settings - I know, I know, bad to mix. But at least we agree on those, and emacs can also automatically (un)tabify).

---

and, yeah, I'd like to use this inside hg diff.

Comment: Cannot he just set up his editor/IDE to remove trailing spaces as well?

Comment: He objects to the diffs it produces.

Comment: If everyone in the team follows the same code conventions  (no trailing spaces) and properly configured IDEs - then this would never appear. At least it never occurs in my teams - because no one commits trailing spaces.